# How to remove a directory from $PATH on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, terminal, path

I want to remove a directory from my PATH directories.

When I run `echo $PATH` I get the following response:

```
/Users/USERNAME/opt/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The anaconda3 should have been gone long ago but somehow is still there. However when I run `which python` I get `/usr/bin/python` I'm very confused as to what's going on

Comment: update your `~/.bash_profile` if you are using `bash` otherwise update you `~/.zshrc` if you are using `zsh`

Comment: @gold_cy please consider answering instead. Comments should not be used for answers (see ["*When shouldn't I comment?*"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)).

Comment: I felt that this wasn’t something that warranted an answer because it was so simple but sure, I can add an answer

Answer (score 1):

First determine which shell you are using by running the following from the command line.

```
ps -p$$ -ocommand=
```

If the output is `zsh` you should make changes to your `$PATH` variable in `${HOME}/.zshrc`.

If the output is `bash` you should make changes to your `$PATH` variable in `${HOME}/.bash_profile`. There is a caveat here though, if your shell is invoked as an interactive non-login shell then changes should be made to your `${HOME}/.bashrc` as your `${HOME}/.bash_profile` should only have the following contents, `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi`. You can read more about this [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

Comment: `.zprofile` would be the preferred place to alter an environment variable like `PATH`, as `.zshrc` would be sourced by shells that have already inherited `PATH` from their parent.

Comment: if they are using a an interactive shell then `.zshrc` should be the place that this information goes, so I have to disagree with you there

Comment: No, because then you are repeatedly adding the same directory to `PATH` every time you create a new shell. It suffices to add it *once* to the initial log-in shell, from which other shells will inherit the path.

Comment: I would honestly leave the `.zprofile` blank and put all this info in `.zshrc` and if it has some data in it, copy it over to `.zshrc`